# Extract rows where value in one column equals value in another column +1?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a tab delimited text file that looks like this:

```
1   10019   10020   rs775809821
1   10055   10055   rs768019142
1   10107   10108   rs62651026
1   10108   10109   rs376007522
1   10128   10128   rs796688738
1   10138   10139   rs368469931
1   10144   10145   rs144773400
1   10146   10147   rs779258992
1   10149   10150   rs371194064
1   10165   10165   s796884232
```

I want to extract the rows in which the value in column 2 is equal to the value in column 1 + 1 and direct them to a new file. So for the above example, the desired output would be:

```
1   10019   10020   rs775809821
1   10107   10108   rs62651026
1   10108   10109   rs376007522
1   10138   10139   rs368469931
1   10144   10145   rs144773400
1   10146   10147   rs779258992
1   10149   10150   s371194064
```

I think this can be accomplished using awk, but I'm not sure where to start. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$3 == $2 + 1' < input > output
```